# Link Slider to Change a Variable Real Time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a pendulum simulation and have a slider next to it to adjust its values (e.g. length, mass, angle etc.) using a slider, but I can't seem to link my code to the slider adequately.

I want the slider to be able to change the variables in real time so the user can play around with the values, but I don't know what the problem is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<style>
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pendulum Javascript Simulation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.0/rangeslider.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
  
  
  
</head>

<body>


<h1>Programmatic value changes</h1>
<br>
<br>
<input type="range" id="js-amount-range" value="0" min="0" max="100")>
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" id="js-amount-input" value="0" min="0" max="100" ></input>

<span> degrees </span>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.0/rangeslider.min.js'></script>

  <section class="wrapper">
        <div id="stars"></div>
        <div id="stars2"></div>
        <div id="stars3"></div>
        <div id="title">
            <span></span>
            <br>
            <span>THE PENDULUM SIMULATION</span>
        </div>
    </section>


 
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width='1270' height='600' style='border:15px solid black'></canvas>
<script>
    function updateSlider(slideAmount) {
        var sliderDiv = document.getElementById("sliderAmount");
        sliderDiv.innerHTML = slideAmount;
    }
</script>
<input id="slide" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="10" onchange="updateSlider(this.value)">
      <script  language="javascript">
   <!--function changeLength() {
   <!--var num1 = parseString(document.getElementById('js-amount-input').value;
      
   <!--}
  
var rangeslider = $('#js-amount-range');
var amount = $('#js-amount-input');

rangeslider
  .rangeslider({
    polyfill: false
  })
  rangeslider.on('input', function() {
    amount[0].value = this.value;
  });

amount.on('input', function() {
  rangeslider.val(this.value).change();
});

   <!-- -->
var Animation = function(canvasId) {
  this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
  this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.t = 0;
  this.timeInterval = 0;
  this.startTime = 0;
  this.lastTime = 0;
  this.frame = 0;
  this.animating = false;
  
  // by Paul Irish
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback){
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();
};



Animation.prototype.getContext = function getContext(){
  return this.context;
};

Animation.prototype.getCanvas = function(){
  return this.canvas;
};

Animation.prototype.clear = function(){
  this.context.clearRect(10, 10, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
};

Animation.prototype.setStage = function(func){
  this.stage = func;
};

Animation.prototype.isAnimating = function(){
  return this.animating;
};

Animation.prototype.getFrame = function(){
  return this.frame;
};

Animation.prototype.start = function(){
  this.animating = true;
  var date = new Date();
  this.startTime = date.getTime();
  this.lastTime = this.startTime;
  
  if (this.stage !== undefined){
    this.stage();
  }
  
  this.animationLoop();
};

Animation.prototype.stop = function(){
  this.animating = false;
};

Animation.prototype.getTimeInterval = function(){
  return this.timeInterval;
};

Animation.prototype.getTime = function(){
  return this.t;
};

Animation.prototype.getFps = function(){
  return this.timeInterval > 0 ? 1000 / this.timeInterval : 0;
};

Animation.prototype.animationLoop = function(){
  var that = this;
  
  this.frame++;
  var date = new Date();
  var thisTime = date.getTime();
  this.timeInterval = thisTime - this.lastTime;
  this.t += this.timeInterval;
  this.lastTime = thisTime;
  
  if (this.stage !== undefined){
    this.stage();
  }
  
  if (this.animating){
    window.requestAnimFrame(function(){
      that.animationLoop();
    });
  }
  
};

window.onload = function (){
  // instantiate new Animation object
  var anim = new Animation("myCanvas");
  var context = anim.getContext();
  var canvas = anim.getCanvas();
  
  
  var amplitude = Math.PI / 2.5; // 45 degrees
  var period = 2000; //ms
  var theta = 0;
  var pendulumLength = 500;
  var pendulumWidth = 10;
  var rotationPointX = canvas.width / 2; //position the pendulum
  var rotationPointY = 50; //position the pendulum
  
  anim.setStage(function(){
    //update
   theta = (amplitude * Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * this.getTime()) / period)) + Math.PI / 2;
    
    //clear
    this.clear();
    
    //draw top circle
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(rotationPointX, rotationPointY, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fill();
    
    //draw shaft
    context.beginPath();
    var endPointX = rotationPointX + (pendulumLength * Math.cos(theta));
    var endPointY = rotationPointY + (pendulumLength * Math.sin(theta));
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(rotationPointX, rotationPointY);
    context.lineTo(endPointX, endPointY);
    context.lineWidth = pendulumWidth;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.strokeStyle = "#555";
    context.stroke();
    
    //draw bottom circle
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(endPointX, endPointY, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    var grd = context.createLinearGradient(endPointX - 50, endPointY - 50, endPointX + 50, endPointY + 50);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "#1d3649");
    grd.addColorStop(0.5, "#3092f4");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "#3092f4");
    context.fillStyle = grd;
    context.fill();
  });
  anim.start();
  
};

   
 var rangeslider = $('#js-amount-range');
var amount = $('#js-amount-input');

rangeslider
  .rangeslider({
    polyfill: false
  })
  .on('input', function() {
    amount[0].value = this.value;
  });

amount.on('input', function() {
  $pendulumLength.val(this.value).change();
});
 
 
</script>

 <!---<script src="js/slider.js"></script>--->
    
 
  <script language="javascript">
 var pendulumLength = $('#js-amount-range');
var amount = $('#js-amount-input');

pendulumLength
  .rangeslider({
    polyfill: false
  })
  pendulumLength.on('input', function() {
    amount[0].value = this.value;
  });

amount.on('input', function() {
  pendulumLength.val(this.value).change();
});
</script>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
 
}

</script> 


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On slider input the variable takes the current value off the slider and and prints it to a span in real time, while it is being dragged.

```js
sliderChange=function(n)
{
var e=n;
$('span').text("Pendulum length is: "+e);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="range" oninput="sliderChange(this.value)" />
<span></span>
```

Comment: But I'm not trying to print out the variable value, I'm trying to change the variable in my code and then have a calculation be performed and have that reflected in the pendulum. For instance, if I were to change the variable PendulumLength using a slider, I want to see the pendulum length change in real time in my pendulum simulation.

Comment: If you look carefully the variable e is changing as the value of slider changes. I have just printed the value of e for readability purposes.You can use e for doing any calculations you want.

Comment: I have made an edit. It shows the pendulum length in real time. You can just use that to do your calculations, which will happen in real time too and will display the final value you want.